# What do you call a biologically assisted robot?

Tags: biology, language, robots, names

A droid is short for android, often a mostly humanoid robot.

A cyborg is a biological being which is improved by robotic elements as part of their body. The word being derived from cybernetics which itself is derived from a Greek word.

So I had the idea to have robots that had biological matter to support it. Like having brain matter to learn the social, language and other analogue stuff and complement/replace the far more complex and rare materials heavy computer systems. As a bonus the brain matter has an in-build flexibility and self repair capability. Similarly other biomatter can be used to create seals, do minor repairs or produce materials like lubricants to keep the robot maintained for longer.

The question is about language and naming: what to call a robot that is supported by biomatter?

To clarify:

- a Cyborg is about robotics implanted and supporting the biological parts. This is the reverse
- this is a language question, not a simple "what to name this" question. As an example the term "space marine" is technically incorrect as the marine part is about the environment, so an espatier would be more proper language to describe the task of the Space Marine.
- this is not about wether you agree with the idea of using biological matter to do tasks in a robot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137732/discussion-on-question-by-demigan-what-do-you-call-a-biologically-assisted-robot).

Answer (score 9):

**A Synthetic**

A **Cyborg** is a biological creature that is born and then has parts of it replaced with mechanical components. Usually the brain remains biological in nature.

A **Synthetic** is a creature that is created by assembling mechanical and biological components, for example a steel exoskeleton with brain and nerve matter grown in a laboratory.

These guys are hard to tell apart at first glance. They both have biological matter integrated with mechanical parts. They might have skin or metal on the outside and organs or gyros on the inside. Very advanced examples can only be distinguished by an invasive scan.

The difference between a cyborg and a synthetic is the manner of creation. Cyborgs are born. Synthetics are "put together" as the etymology implies.

Answer (score 7):

## Orgasm

This is a question of language, and you are looking for a
parallel inverse to **cyborg**. Let’s break that down.

Cyborg standards for “cybernetic organism”. A cyborg is an organism that is enhanced with cybernetics, and an organism is “a whole biological being composed of independent parts”. “Cybernetic” has a more complicated definition, but it’s ended up degraded into just meaning “machine/robot-like”.

To parallel “organism”, we pick a word that depicts a whole *machine being,* composed of independent parts. The perfect word for this is “mechanism” or “assembly”. I favor the latter because the a robot body is not wholly mechanical, it is also electrical, so “mechanism” is reductive. The other half, fortunately, is much easier, since we can just borrow “organic” from “organism”. This gives you the name “organic assembly”.

Then, to parallel how “cyborg” abbreviates “cybernetic organism”, we abbreviate both halves of the name:

Organic Assembly -> Org-assem.

Then, by the same process of linguistic elision that turns “family” into “famly” and “camera” into “camra”, we lose the interstitial vowel.

Org-assem -> **Orgasm**.

This has the benefit of verisimilitude, since we’ve seen the same thing happen with Web Assembly, which becomes WASM, pronounced “wazzum” and rhyming with orgasm.

Comment: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) What a Great Name!

Answer (score 1):

> The word being derived from cybernetics which itself is derived from a Greek word.

A brief peek at the [etymology of cybernetics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cybernetics) shows that it comes from a Greek root word to do with steering, possibly via a French word referring to systems of governance. A computer driving a meatsuit could just as plausibly be described as a cybernetic system as a conventionally-grown brain operating some artificial mechanism.

For a real-world example of using the term in this way, consider the US military projects involving combining MEM and electronic systems and regular organic moths and beetles to create new hybrid systems: https://spectrum.ieee.org/cyborg-moth-gets-a-new-radio. The DARPA project was entitled [HI-MEMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Insect_Micro-Electro-Mechanical_Systems), for Hybrid Insect Micro-Electro-Mechanical Systems, but the resulting creations were often referred to as "cybernetic".

Neologisms are of course strictly opinion-based, as you haven't offered us a conlang or any other framework to build in, but you could always follow the DARPA approach and make suitable acronym (HOMEMS, with O-for-organic, would be easiest, and nicely sounds a little like "humans", though the "micro" bit is aa little awkward). Scifi works are replete with neologisms of varying qualities. Orion's Arm, as always, took things a bit too far with ["*biaioid*"](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/4dc561a121794). I'm sure you can find other examples, perhaps with easier pronunciations.

Answer (score 1):

**Biomech**

"Mech" referring to the fundamental machine nature of the thing, with the prefix "bio" modifying to show that this is the type of machine it is.   Mech also is popularly used to refer to humanoid fighting robots / fighting vehicle and so "biomech" is especially appropriate if the object considered is in this category.

An analogy would be tech - "biotech" is biological tech, "nanotech" is nanoscale tech, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Normally "cyborg" covers any combination of biological and non-biological.  Motoko Kusanagi and a Cyberdyne Systems T-800 Model 101 are both cyborgs under normal usage.

One option if you want to make a distinction would be to add an adjective instead of making a separate word.  "Cyborg" is either case but a "Type One Cyborg" is an originally entirely biological organism that has been altered, and a "Type Two Cyborg" is created as such.

"Type one"/"Type two" could be replaced with something more evocative  "Natural cyborg"/"synthetic cyborg", "augmented cyborg"/constructed cyborg", "wet cyborg"/"dry cyborg", and so on.

You could also go the route that one of them is just a "cyborg" and the other always gets the adjective.

Finally you could as you originally suggest, pick a new term for one or the other.

Some terms that have been used in science fiction you could use, possibly with some semantic drift from their normal usage:

Augment/Augmented  Used in Deus Ex to mean a human with cybernetic parts and Star Trek to mean a genetically engineered human.  You could use this to mean the biological first cyborg, and use "cyborg" to mean the machine first cyborg.

Android:  Widely used to mean a human mimicking robot.  You could use this to mean specificaly robots with a biological skin like a T-800 but not a humanoid without a biological skin.

Bioroid: Used in Transhuman Space and Appleseed among other works to mean a product of biogenesis: Biological life created artificially from scratch, usually via nanotechnology.  It's a portmanteau of "biological android"  You could drift this to mean an artificial first cyborg.

Biot: Similar to boiroid and less common but it's "biological robot".  It's more appropriate for non-humanoid examples like the alien biots in Rendezvous with Rama.

You could also borrow at term from mythology, particularly one used in fantasy.  "Golem" or "zombie" could work for instance.

Beyond that you could just coin something for your setting:  Biomech, wetbot, turboencabulator, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

**Cyborg** is essentially a contraction of **cyb**ernetically enhanced **org**anism.
So the other way around you get a **orga**nically enhanced **mech**anism, or an **Orga-Mech** for short.

You could use Bio instead of Orga as prefix, as already suggested by Willk, but to me that would indicate that the non-mechanical parts have a fully biological origin, which sort-of excludes the use of artificially constructed/grown organic parts.

Comment: The androids would take issue with the implication of this definition that they are not organisms.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the word **psytron**.

This comes from the old video game [*Star Control*](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Microsoft_DOS/manual/Formated/Star_Control.pdf), which had *cyborg* and *psytron* battle modes.

The cyborg mode was where `the human player makes strategic choices. But when battle occurs, the computer takes over full combat responsibility.`

The psytron mode was the opposite of that, where `the human player fights all battles, while the computer decides all strategy.`

Answer (score -1):

Grobyc (pronounced like ”grob ice”).

That's about as reverse of cyborg as you can get.